# Show that if some nontrivial linear combination of vectors $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ is $\vec{0}$, then $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are parallel.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

I've never been that great at writing proofs, but I'm getting a bit better. I think I have the answer correct, but I don't know if I'm missing anything. My logic seems right but there may be some minute detail that I'm leaving out. Can anybody give any feedback on this? Thanks.

---

$\vec{0}$ being a nontrivial linear combination of $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ implies that there exists a non-zero $a$ or $b$ such that $a\vec{u}=-b\vec{v}$. Without loss of generality, assume $a\neq 0$. Then divide by $a$ and the equality holds: $\vec{u}=-\frac{b}{a}\vec{v}$. And since $-\frac{b}{a}\vec{v}$ is a scalar multiple of $\vec{u}$, it remains that $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are parallel.

More rigorous proof:
\begin{align*}
\vec{0}=a\vec{u}+b\vec{v}&\Longrightarrow a\neq 0\vee b\neq 0&&\text{Given}\\
&\Longrightarrow a\vec{u}=-b\vec{v}\\
&\Longrightarrow \vec{u}=-\frac{b}{a}\vec{v}&&\text{WLOG assume $a\neq 0$}\\
&\Longrightarrow \vec{u}\text{ and }\vec{v}\text{ are parallel.}
\end{align*}

Comment: By hypothesis, at least one scalar is non zero. Suppose $a\neq 0$. So you can divide by $a$ and then $a\vec{u}+b\vec{v}=\vec{0}$ implies that $\vec{u}=-b/a\vec{v}$.

Comment: This should be fine: it shows that the relationship between the two vectors is that one is a scalar multiple of the other, that scalar being the _proportion_ between $a$ and $b$, and also indicating why $a$ and $b$ _must_ be non-zero.  The one "correction" I would suggest is this also shows that $\overrightarrow{u}$ and $\overrightarrow{v}$ are parallel if $a$ and $b$ have _opposite_ signs and anti-parallel if they have the same sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost perfect.

But, we don't have $a\ne 0$ *and* $b\ne 0$, only $a\ne 0$ *or* $b\ne 0$. So, one side might be $0$, but then the other is again parallel to it.

Comment: But if one is zero, how can it be that $a\vec{u}=-b\vec{v}$?

Comment: Although in fairness you could dismiss the case where one of them is zero since then one concludes one of the vectors is zero and it's trivial.

Comment: @agent154, perhaps $a=0$ and $\vec{v}=0$, but the other two are nonzero.

Comment: @Sharkos How could I modify my proof (aside from changing the first line to *or* instead of *and* to account for this? Can I say that one of three conditions are true without having some long winded conjunction? I mean - either a and v is 0 while the others are nonzero, b and u are 0, or a and b are nonzero while u and v are zero.

Comment: @agent154, please, see my comment above.

Comment: The magic phrase is WLOG or Without Loss of Generality. One has either $a\neq 0$ or $b\neq 0$ and then by possibly relabeling $u,v$ and $a,b$ we assume $b\neq 0$.

Comment: @Sigur Does my above edit work properly?

Comment: @agent154, the text is good, but I would say that $\vec u$ is a multiple scalar of $\vec v$ (just personal preference). Now, the first arrow is strange. You don't have an implication. You have the linear combination with that hypothesis.